# DB2 and PHP not working on Apache2 but on CLI

Tags: php, db2

I've installed the IBM DB/2 PHP Extension via PECL. Astonishingly, access to my DB/2 server works flawlessly via PHP CLI by using the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

$connection_string="DATABASE=NAMZPR1;HOSTNAME=172.20.10.162;PORT=50055;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=bouser;PWD=xxx";

$conn = db2_connect($connection_string, "", "");

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded. \n";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo "Connection failed. " . db2_conn_errormsg() . " \n";
}
 
?>
```

when calling the PHP via browser from Apache2 it throws "Connection failed".

I've edited the appropriate PHP.INI file and added the extension as well as added

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/clidriver/odbc_cli/clidriver/lib

to the Apache httpd.conf file.

I am puzzled. It does not work. What part am I missing? Both the PHP CLI and the Apache PHP Module should ouput "Connection succeeded".

The error I get when calling the URL with the PHP is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function db2_connect()
> in /var/www/html/db2.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
> /var/www/html/db2.php on line 8

I've managed to load the ibm_db2 module in Apache, here is the output:

> ibm_db2 IBM Db2 and compatible databases support  enabled Module
> release   2.1.7 Binary data mode (ibm_db2.binmode)    1 - DB2_BINARY DB2
> instance name (ibm_db2.instance_name) no value Commitment control
> (ibm_db2.i5_allow_commit) 0 - DB2_I5_TXN_NO_COMMIT System naming mode
> (ibm_db2.i5_sys_naming)   0 - disabled

My message from the Apache Error Log File is

> > [Thu Feb 09 16:04:33.929426 2023] [php:warn] [pid 629664] [client 172.20.11.18:57220] PHP Warning:  db2_connect(): SQLGetDiagRec returned -2 (is the driver working?) in /var/www/html/db2.php on line
> > 8

*Edit: I've managed to set the instance name*

IBM Db2 and compatible databases support    enabled
Module release  2.1.7
Binary data mode (ibm_db2.binmode)  1 - DB2_BINARY
DB2 instance name (ibm_db2.instance_name)   db2inst1
Commitment control (ibm_db2.i5_allow_commit)    0 - DB2_I5_TXN_NO_COMMIT
System naming mode (ibm_db2.i5_sys_naming)  0 - disabled

Environment Variables:

```
export IBM_DB_HOME=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/lib64
export LIBPATH=/home/admini/sqllib/lib
export PATH=/home/admini/sqllib/bin:$PATH
```

so weired :-(

Comment: Sounds like the php.ini files differ, the CLI variant does include the DB extension, the one used by the apache server does not. Which version of php are you using inside your http server? The apache module or a fpm server? Check `phpinfo()` to make sure the db extension is actually loaded.

Comment: Apache Module. Indeed, the extension is not loaded. What to do next?

Comment: The different "flavors" of how to use php use different configuration files (".ini" files). You need to find the right one and add the extension, just as you did for the one you altered to load the extension for the CLI flavor of PHP. Again `phpinfo()` will assist here: near to top it states which configuration file has been loaded.

Comment: no chance, the two files (for CLI and Apache) are identical. Doublechecked it.

Comment: You have restarted the http server, haven't you?

Comment: yes I've restartet the server.

Comment: Please edit your question to add facts (don't use comments because they are not searchable). When run in browser (not cli), show the values of `$_ENV["PATH"]`  and `$_ENV["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]` and `$_ENV["IBM_DB_HOME"]`

Comment: What does your http server's error log file reveal when you start it and it tries to load the db module?

Comment: Is your Db2 server an i-series (as/400). If so, you should have placed that vital information into your first question, and you should specify exactly which driver name and version you are using!  If not, you've loaded the wrong driver.

Comment: no, it's not an i-series

Comment: There should be no mention of i5 anywhere. Please edit your question to show the browser output of the env variables asked in a previous comment of mine above.

Comment: I've edited the question again

Comment: It may be that files of more than one Db2-driver are on your PATH/LIBPATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH. You mix `/opt/ibm/db2/...` and `/home/admin1/sqllib...`. Don't do that.  Verify env vars __ONLY__ via `$_ENV` inside browser or use `phpinfo()` in browser  (not cli). If you are using `/opt/ibm/db2/...` then verify that the account that runs Apache has rwx access to all of that directory tree and that the startup file(s) dot in the correct `db2profile` (example `. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile` ) before starting apache.